# Building a virtual camera for OS X

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

I need to get a synthetic generated video stream in a program like skype. The audio part is easy. There is a project called [Soundflower](https://code.google.com/p/soundflower/) which is an adapter. It presents a virtual audio destination device on the one side and a video source on the other side. I am searching for the same solution for OSX. Except I only need the part how to present it as a virtual camera. Do not misunderstood, I do not need a "ready to use" tool, I need the way how to develop it. So a ready to use tool is only helpful with the source code.

In the Windows world, where I came from, I already programmed such a Virtual Camera using DirectShow. Now I am searching for a similar solution in the OSX world.

Comment: Were you able to create the virtual video destination device? I'd love to know how you achieved this. thx

Comment: No, the project was dropped so I stopped searching for a solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This depends to some extent on the application with which you wish to interface.  If it is an old-school QuickTime app (32-bit, 10.8 or earlier), you would need to write a QuickTime `vdig` (video digitiser) component. This is basically a plugin that provides a certain interface that can be dynamically enumerated and invoked by any QT-compatible app.  However, this is all now deprecated (as of 10.9)!

The modern approach is to use the Core Media I/O Framework.  Unfortunately, it isn't as thoroughly documented as most of the other frameworks, as it is used by only a fraction of the developer base (who need to create hardware interfaces).

There's an SDK project available, which contains the CoreMedia framework plus some example code:

- [ADC CoreMediaIO SDK](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html)

Take a look specifically at `IOVideoSampleDevice`.

You probably won't need a `kext` (kernel extension) as you won't be interfacing with real hardware. So hopefully you will just be able to get by with implementing the required `CMIO` interfaces and registering your device type.

There's a great book available which covers driver development for OS X and iOS:

- [OS X and iOS Kernel Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430235365)

(Disclaimer: the authors are colleges and friends of mine.)

QuickTime used to be the DirectShow equivalent. Now, CoreMedia and friends have superseded it, with a far more modern and flexible API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't believe someone can top your answer but I will give that a chance as I hoped for a answer like: "Sure, there is a a project XY which does exactly what you want and the source is BSD." :-) You show me the stony dark valley :-) Like QuickTime, DirectShow is now superseded after torturing developers for years ( I do not know if QuickTime was a similar mess). I started downloading your suggestion already. I guess in about an hour you will get your green checkmark.

Comment: Sure. :) Your request is somewhat a niche topic, so I'd be somewhat surprised if there were a ready-made project that does just this. I've seen such samples for QT, but not CMIO. But this SDK does have a complete example, so you should be able to extract most of what you need from that. Having worked with both DirectShow and QuickTime, I have many more scars from DS! QuickTime is old-fashioned but DS is a nightmare.

Comment: as of October 2015, the mentioned CoreMediaIO SDK project does not compile on Yosemite or El Capitan. I tried to make it work and was able to solve a lot of issue by removing the old source code within the "source" folder and add the equivalent frameworks since it seems they have been bundled into frameworks (added: accelerate, evenkit, audiotoolbox, coreaudio,coreaudiokit, carbon, audiounit). Then I ran into core C++ errors i couldn't get away within a couple hours and decided to let go and I'm hoping an Apple employee would fix the sample source code and we will all be happily ever after...

Comment: @user1988824 Any luck with the virtual camera?

Comment: @DmitryGutsulyak no luck. I went through a lot of code and examples I found online. I remember being able to get a hold of the video / audio inputs but could not create the virtual device.

Comment: Wow.. with so many apps that do that, I cant believe there is no documentation. Take ManyCam or Snap Camera for example, they are trendy and very 2020.